# How to authenticate user by phone and SMS (no password) with OpenIddict

Tags: openiddict

I have a mobile app that requires authentication by phone number.
As this is my app if I had login and password I would use `Resource owner password credentials flow`.
Is it a good idea to use the same flow for the phone number scenario?

Comment: were you able to implement this?

Comment: You can create a new grant type for that and consume it the same as `Resource owner password credentials flow` in the same controller method

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the authorization code flow for this scenario, it will give you much more flexibility for the login part.

Comment: Doing SMS verification via MVC/Razor Page?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool IsSMSCodeGrantType(this OpenIddictRequest request)
{
    if (request is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));
    }
    return string.Equals(request.GrantType, MyGrantTypes.SMS_Code, StringComparison.Ordinal);
}
```

```
[HttpPost("~/connect/token"), IgnoreAntiforgeryToken, Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Exchange()
{
...
    else if (request.IsSMSCodeGrantType())
    {
        /// Derive from SignInManager and implement SMS check and SMS send
        var result = await _signInManager.CheckSMSSignInAsync(user, request.Password, lockoutOnFailure: true);
    }
```

Comment: what password did you use? In question, you have SMS (no password), is it an OTP?